# What does std::owner_less do?

Tags: c++

I've read that std::owner_less performs "owner-based rather than value-based" ordering, that two smart pointers are equivalent if they "point to subobjects of the same object" - what does that exactly mean?

As a test case, I have written the following code:

```
struct T {};

int main() {
    T* t = new T();

    std::shared_ptr<T> a(t);
    std::shared_ptr<T> b(t);

    std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>> set1;
    set1.insert(a);
    std::cout << set1.size() << std::endl;
    set1.insert(b);
    std::cout << set1.size() << std::endl;

    std::set<std::shared_ptr<T>, std::owner_less<std::shared_ptr<T>>> set2;
    set2.insert(a);
    std::cout << set2.size() << std::endl;
    set2.insert(b);
    std::cout << set2.size() << std::endl;
}
```

And the output is 1 1 1 2. It seems to me that if std::owner_less performs "owner-based" comparison, shouldn't it consider a and b to be the same, while the default comparator treats them as different? The result of my code seems to be saying just the opposite though.

Comment: If your intent was that both `a` and `b` should share ownership of the object `t`, then you must create `b` using the copy constructor of `shared_ptr` to share ownership with `a` as in `std::shared_ptr<T> b(a)`. Constructing a `shared_ptr` from a raw pointer always creates a new owner with a reference count of one.

Comment: [std::shared_ptr::owner_before](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/owner_before) provides example similar to what you want IMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
std::shared_ptr<T> a(t);
std::shared_ptr<T> b(t);
```

This is undefined behavior when the `shared_ptr`s are destroyed; the two `shared_ptr`s do not know of each other's existence, and each will attempt to delete `t`.

---

`owner_less` can be thought of as "ordering on the address of the (real or metaphorical) control block". Thus, it considers equivalent two `shared_ptr` (and `weak_ptr`) if they share ownership or are both empty:

```
struct T { int x, y; };

std::shared_ptr<T> a(new T{});
std::shared_ptr<T> b = a;

std::shared_ptr<int> c(a, &a->y); // aliasing constructor

std::shared_ptr<T> d(a.get(), [](T*){}); // null deleter to avoid no double delete
std::shared_ptr<T> e(std::shared_ptr<T>(), a.get()); // "non-owning" empty shared_ptr with a non-null stored pointer
```

`a`, `b`, and `c` are all equivalent according to `owner_less` because they share ownership. `d` doesn't share ownership with `a` (it has its own "control block"), so it's different according to `owner_less`. Likewise for `e`, which is empty (owns nothing) but has a non-null stored pointer.

The default comparator simply compares the stored pointer, or `get()`. It will see `a`, `b`, `d`, and `e` as all equivalent and `c` as different (assuming that you converted both sides to `shared_ptr<void>` so that they are comparable).

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I actually know those two lines will cause problems but just used it as a way to expose the issue, but I wasn't familiar with aliasing constructors. Could you also explain why the default comparator (I am assuming it is just std::less<std::shared_ptr<T>>?) considers a and b to be the same?

Comment: I'm not sure if it really is UB in this case because `T` has a trivial destructor, but in the general case it definitely is.

Comment: @DanielH You forgot the double free.

Comment: @DanielH It is UB because as `a` and `b` goes out of scope, `delete` operator will be called twice on the memory allocated for `t`. Double delete is always UB.

Comment: @JulienVillemure-Fréchette Yeah, you're right. I was just thinking of the destructor, not the deallocation.